# Ошибка после контейнеризации в selenium xpath

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, xpath

столкнулся с такой проблемой:
При работе кода на моём компьютере скрипт выполняет все корректно и не выводит ошибок. Запускаю через vs code на OS windows.
Решил собрать в контейнер и начались беды. Ранее рабочая функция xpath теперь уверяет, что должны быть element, вместо elements.
[image: А вот и ошибка]

Но везде где я использую xpath я паршу массивы данных, а не элемент. В подтверждение вот часть кода, где я их использую:

```
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--window-size=1920,1080')
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage') 
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), chrome_options=chrome_options)

try:
    #start_time = datetime.datetime.now()

    driver.get("Здесь могла быть ваша реклама)")  
    url = "Здесь могла быть ваша реклама)"
    driver.implicitly_wait(5)
      
    sait=[]
    driver.implicitly_wait(5)   
    id_find = [x.get_attribute("id") for x in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@data-marker='item']")]
    while True:

        #proverka_na_oshibku()      
   
        while i<60:

            #proverka_na_oshibku()

            id_find1 = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@data-marker='item']")            
            title = id_find1[i].get_attribute("id")            

            if title not in id_find:

                items = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@data-marker='item-photo']")          
                items[i].click()

                load_price_saita()

                i+=1               
            else:
                i=60
        id_find = [x.get_attribute("id") for x in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@data-marker='item']")]        
        driver.get("Здесь могла быть ваша реклама)")        
        time.sleep(randint(10,100))

        i=0       
  
except Exception as ex:

    print(ex)
```

Как видно в коде - нужны элементы... Или пора уже покупать очочки? Коль кто сталкивался с таким - подскажите в чем беда?

Comment: Какая у вас версия selenium? Попробуйте `pip install selenium==4.2.0`.

Comment: Действительно, докер подгрузил более старую версию, проблема решилась)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В данном случае, в контейнере некорректно погрузился selenium. После указание версии (`pip install selenium==4.2.0`) - все стало работать нормально.